# snackbar con base de datos,

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc

quiero mostrar un snackbar con datos obtenidos a través de una base de datos, el problema es que el snackbar no se muestra, les dejare el codigo que estoy utilzando:

edit: borre el codigo y este es el actual

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

                    View v1 = findViewById(R.id.content_main);
                    int height = 20;
                    int width = 20;
                    String query = "select top 1 tipo,descripcion from reporte where nombre_ruta = '"+marker.getTitle()+"';";
                    String query2="select AVG(valoracion)as valoracion from valorar where nombre_ruta = '"+marker.getTitle()+"';";


                    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.starmarcadores);
                    Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
                    Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
                    Drawable drawable= new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), smallMarker);

                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);

                    try {
                                    con = connectionclass (un, passwords, db, ip);
                                    if (con == null) {
                                        isConnected(getApplicationContext());
                                    } else if(con!=null){
                                        Log.d("este camino","este camino");
                                        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                                        stmt.setQueryTimeout(2);
                                        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                                        while (rs.next()) {
                                            Log.d("tipo",rs.getString("tipo"));
                                            Log.d("descripcion",rs.getString("descripcion"));

                                            SpannableStringBuilder snackbarText = new SpannableStringBuilder();
                                            snackbarText.append("Valoración: ");
                                            snackbarText.append("");
                                           // snackbarText.setSpan(span, 13, 14, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                                            snackbarText.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            snackbarText.append("Estado de la ruta: posible " + rs.getString("tipo") );
                                            snackbarText.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            snackbarText.append("Descripción del reporte: " + rs.getString("descripcion"));

                                            snackbar = Snackbar.make(v1, snackbarText, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                                    .setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
                                                    .setAction("Opciones", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                                            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar)
                                                                    .setTitle("Opciones")
                                                                    .setMessage("Te gustaria valorar o reportar la ruta?")
                                                                    .setCancelable(true)
                                                                    .setPositiveButton("Valorar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Valoracion2.class);
                                                                            i.putExtra("Nruta", marker.getTitle().toString());
                                                                            startActivity(i);
                                                                        }
                                                                    })
                                                                    .setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null)
                                                                    .setNegativeButton("Reportar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                                                        }
                                                                    }).show();
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                            View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                                            TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                            textView.setMaxLines(5);
                                            snackbar.show();
                                            con.close();
                                        }
                                    }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

el problema ahora es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero ya carga la snackbar y los datos, solo el mensaje es el problema

Comment: recibes algun error o warning cuando ejecutas la aplicacion?

Comment: No, en el logcat no se muestra nada, solo no aparece

Comment: la conexion a tu base de datos es un singleton?

Comment: No, no es singleton

Comment: que devuelve entonces isConnected(getApplicationContext());?

Comment: Solo un Crouton que dice q no hay conexion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50029/discussion-between-sioesi-and-zhet).

Comment: Igual no te muestra la Snackbar porque la consulta no devuelve nada y por eso no entra en rs.next(). ¿Has comprobado que la consulta este correcta y devuelva algo?

Comment: Si, si devuelve valores, hay insert para q no sea nula

Comment: Agregue el repositorio al chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes revisar tu conexión ya que es la que determina que se muestre el SnackBar

```
 con = connectionclass (un, passwords, db, ip);
    if (con == null) {
             isConnected(getApplicationContext());
     } else {
             //Muestra SnackBar.
```

---

Es importante también, revises dentro de tu `LogCat`, ya que pudieras tener una buena conexión, y obtener correctamente el `Resultset` pero al obtener datos como  `"tipo"`  y `"descripcion"` estos no se obtengan realmente:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
 if (rs.next()) {
    SpannableStringBuilder snackbarText = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    snackbarText.append("Valoración: ");
    snackbarText.append(valoracion + " ");
    snackbarText.setSpan(span, 13, 14, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    snackbarText.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    snackbarText.append("Estado de la ruta: posible " +  rs.getString("tipo"));
    snackbarText.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    snackbarText.append("Descripción del reporte: " + rs.getString("descripcion"));
```

---

El problema es cierras la conexión pero la instancia es nula!

```
con.close();
```

Debes validar

```
if(con != null){
  con.close();
}
```

o únicamente cerrar la conexión al final del else, en el cual se determina que la conexión se realizo:

```
con = connectionclass (un, passwords, db, ip);
    if (con == null) {
        isConnected(getApplicationContext());
        Log.d("conexion nula","conexion nula");
    } else {
       ...
       ...
       con.close();
     }
```

---

El error que ahora comentas:

> Invalid State : the resultSet object is closed()

Se debe a que intentas obtener datos del cursor (`rs`) pero no existe.

Comment: Lo mismo propuse yo, en mi respuesta (que tu puedes ver) sin embargo el OP asegura que sigue sin aparecer.

Comment: Hola @sioesi, acabo de ver tu respuesta, veo que la eliminaste. Bueno creo que este tipo de preguntas tiende a ser "amplia" ya que el OP no agrega datos desplegados en LogCat, con eso se puede determinar rápidamente el problema :(

Comment: @sioesi yo tampoco puedo ver tu respuesta

Comment: @Joacer la abri nuevamente

Comment: pude determinar que la conexión no es nula, pero aun sigo con el problema que el logcat no me dice exactamente el error

Comment: @zhet al revisar define como "Verbose" y se desplegaran todos los mensajes incluyendo errores, para ver errores cambia a "Error", revisa si sale algo! =)

Comment: @Elenasys,agregado, la app se cayo, y edite la pregunta con el logcat

Comment: @zhet he agregado la actualización.

Comment: ya no se cae con el verbose, pero sigue sin vizualizarse

Comment: el problema ocurre en el if del rs.next(), coloque un log.d y este no aparecio

Comment: @zhet validaste lo que comento en mi respuesta? if(con != null){
  con.close();
}

Comment: @ya se muestra la snackbar, pero me muestra un error, dejare una foto

Comment: la dejare como correcta, ya solucione el problema y fue la que mas se acerco al error

Comment: @zhet El último error que comentas, si cierras el cursor (rs) no puedes acceder al recordset, antes debes obtener los datos y después cerrar el cursor =)

Comment: Como lo solucionaste? Me alegro que hayas resuelto el problema :D

Comment: aunque suene extraño, solo hize un rebuild y funciono bien hasta el problema de arriba, el problema lo solucione borrando con.close(), dentro del if del rs.next()

Comment: @zhet cuando obtengas los datos de la conexión debes cerrarla con con.close(), no es buena práctica dejar abierta la conexión =P

Comment: y como? si la saco del if y la coloco afuera, la instancia es nula, si la borro, el problema desaparece, tengo un login que el con.close dentro del if funciona perfecto, pero con este, nose porque genera ese error

Comment: afuera del if, validas: if(con != null){
  con.close();
}

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate en este código

```
con = connectionclass(un, passwords, db, ip);
if (con == null) {
    isConnected(getApplicationContext());
    //creas el snackbarText sin los datos de la base
}else{ 
    //creas el snackbarText con los datos de la base
}
```

Si la conexión es nula, no crea por lo tanto parece ser que el error es eso, que si es nula no hace nada por eso no se dibuja, debes iniciar la variable `con` y asegurarte que hay una conexion a la base de datos SI Y SOLO SI, quieres que tu `snackbarText` tenga datos de la base de datos, deberia ser algo asi :

```
con = connectionclass(un, passwords, db, ip);
if (con == null) {
    //aqui conectar correctamente la base de datos
}
//seguir el tratamiento
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setQueryTimeout(1);
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

SI, el escenario es distinto y NO NECESARIAMENTE los datos van a salir de la base de datos, deberias seguir el orden que tienes

```
con = connectionclass(un, passwords, db, ip);
if (con == null) {
    isConnected(getApplicationContext());
}else{ 
    //creas el snackbarText 
}
```

Con la diferencia que en el `if (con == null)` aparte de llamar al metodo `isConnected(getApplicationContext());` dibujar tu `snackbarText` sin los datos de la base.

Comment: probe con el segundo metodo y puse 2 Toast en el caso que fuera nula o existiera conexion, el caso es que tomo el camino de else, donde la conexion no era nula, pero la snackbar sigue sin mostrarse

Comment: y verificaste que la consulta traiga datos ?  if (rs.next()) {

Comment: si, en el mismo toast coloque el rs.getString("tipo") y si lo mostro

Comment: @sioesi ya veo, si el usuario comenta "Si Quito el código de la conexión, la snackbar se muestra", es algo obvio que la conexión o datos que se obtienen es lo que provoca el problema, definitivamente creo que es amplia esta pregunta =/

Comment: Si, mucho... ademas asegura que si imprime los valores que devuelve `rs` y los obtiene correctamente, es dificil poder generar el error :/

Comment: Creo que sin el logcat o sin hacer una depuración más a fondo no se puede llegar a una solución correcta, porque pueden ser mil cosas